# Is there a way for the Oracle Data Integrator to extract data from MongoDB

Tags: oracle, mongodb, etl

I'm trying to move snapshots of data from our MongoDB into our Oracle BI data store.

From the BI team I've been asked to make the data available for ODI, but I haven't been able to find an example of that being done.

Is it possible and what do I need to implement it?

If there is a more generic way of getting MongoDB data into Oracle then I'm happy to propose that as well.

**Versions**

- MongoDB: 2.0.1
- ODI: 11.1.1.5
- Oracle: 11.2g

Edit:
This is something that will be queried once a day, maybe twice but at this stage the BI report granularity is daily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ODI, under the Topology tab and Physical Architecture sub-tab, you can see all technologies that are supported out of the box. MongoDB is not one of them. There are also no Knowledge Modules available for importing/exporting from/to MongoDB.

ODI supports implementing your own technologies and your own Knowledge Modules.
[This manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/integrate.1111/e12645/toc.htm) will get you started with developing your won Knowledge module, and [in one of the other manuals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/nav/portal_booklist.htm) i'm sure you can find an explanation on how to implement your own technologies. (Ctrl-F for "Data integrator")

If you're lucky, you might find someone else who has already implemented it. Your best places to look would be [The Oracle Technology Network Forum](https://forums.oracle.com), or a forum related to MongoDB.

Instead of creating a direct link, you could also take an easier workaround. Export the data from the MongoDB to a format that ODI supports, and MongoDB can extract to. CSV or XML maybe? Then load the data trough ODI into the oracle database. I think... that will be the best option, unless you have to do this frequently...

Comment: thanks for the answer. I haven't been able to find a connection to MongoDB but we are investigating building our own Knowledge Module to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the blog post below for an option;
https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/entry/odi_mongodb_and_a_java

Cheers
David